# Authorization token never goes in ReactJS request header using Axios and Backend with Spring Boot Security

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

This might seem a duplicate but it's not. I have learned a lot the others questions/answers.

I this case I have Spring Boot Security enabled generating a JWT token when user logs in - that's working well.

When the access token is returned I need to make a call to a protected endpoint to get some info from that user.

In the Frontend side I am using ReactJS with Axios, every call works fine unless I try to call a protected endpoint passing the token in the `Authorization` property on the header.

The odd thing here is that when testing using Postman it works perfectly well:
1) Login with email and password
2) Get returned token and make any call to any protected endpoint

What does Postman do so different from what I am doing that the `Authorization` on the header never gets sent?

I am using an interceptor to inject the token on the requests when the token exists on the local storage (and it does exist):

```
export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: ROOT_API
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    config.headers["Accept"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    config.headers["If-Modified-Since"] = "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT";
    config.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";

    const token = await getToken();
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    console.log("config => ", config);

    return config;
});
```

But every call I do I get a 401 status code, because, of course, the token never gets on the API on the server side.

[image]

As you can see on the picture that is the header that was supposed to be sent. But when I check on the server side it's always null.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/yajra/5f5551649b20c8f668aec48549ef5c1f

Comment: Thanks @AhmedRebai but that didn't help, this is driving me crazy, what is that Postman does different from my request call?